# Filtered post assigned to categories

Tags: categories

I have recently purchased a theme and have created my categories for my primary menu.

I have created a category called 'Reviews'. The aim of this category is to filter All of the reviewed articles (from other categories) into a top reviews page.

The 'Reviews' page is in the grid style format.

Is there any way of ensuring that the reviews are only associated with its primary category and when clicked on for the full article the user is only taken there rather than duplicated as a 'review'  category?

I hope that makes sense

Please see the link below as an example and see where the user is taken when they click for the full article.

However in the breadcrumb and taxonomy of the site

Comment: Sorry here is the link

Comment: http://www.itechwearer.com/category/reviews/

Comment: You can and should add additional information to you question by [editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/203631/edit) it.